# Outputting values from a loop resulting in value of zero

Tags: php, postgresql

I am currently trying to output the value of an array using a for loop.

I have tried outputting the query that is running in the loop (Resulting in an echo of 24 queries)

## 1

```
$number_of_beams = 24; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_beams; $i++)
    {
      $query = "SELECT fitacf_data.time,
      SUM(fitacf_data.num_pts) AS point_total
      FROM 
      fitacf_data
      WHERE abbrev = '" . $radar_array[0]['radar_abbrev'] ."'
      AND fitacf_data.beam = '" . $i . "'
      GROUP BY fitacf_data.time";
      $result = pg_query($query) or die('Error: ' . pg_last_error());
      while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        $beam_total_array[] = $row; 
      }
      echo $i
      echo $beam_total_array[0]['point_total'] . "<br><br>";
    }
```

If I hard code $i to any value from 0-23 echo $beam_total_array[0]['point_total']; outputs the correct value 24 times.

ie:

## 2

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_beams; $i++)
{
  $query = "SELECT fitacf_data.time,
  SUM(fitacf_data.num_pts) AS point_total
  FROM 
  fitacf_data
  WHERE abbrev = '" . $radar_array[0]['radar_abbrev'] ."'
  AND fitacf_data.beam = '5'
  GROUP BY fitacf_data.time";
  $result = pg_query($query) or die('Error: ' . pg_last_error());
  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    $beam_total_array[] = $row; 
  }
  echo $i
  echo $beam_total_array[0]['point_total'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

$i is returning 0-23 as expected.

If I run the code as shown in #1 using the $i variable the output is 0 for the 24 times.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Running db queries inside a loop is often a sign of bad code.

Comment: You'll need to add some debugging code to view $query and see if it is what you are expecting. Also, what Felippe said - you'll want to re-think your code. Let the database engine do the "heavy lifting" and return only the results that you want, then iterate over them with php script. SQL databases are very powerful and very fast, so lean on their processing power when you can instead of using PHP code and calling query after query, which is horribly slow and contentious.

Comment: Example: WHERE abbrev = '" . $radar_array[0]['radar_abbrev'] ."' AND (fitacf_data.beam >= 0 AND fitacf_data.beam < 24) GROUP BY...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're declaring $i as a string, which has a value of 0.  Remove the double quotes around $i:  `AND fitacf_data.beam = ' . $i . '`